# Magento: Showing sibling categories in layered navigation

Tags: magento

I would like to add sibling categories to layered navigation (whenever a customer is is 
already one layer in).

In other words: lets say I have a category called 'Animals' and sub categories named 'Cats' 'Dogs' and 'Lions' respectively, if a customer clicks on 'Lions' I want them to see in "Shop by category" Cats and Dogs.

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the [Multi-Category Layered Navigation](http://www.itoris.com/magento-layered-navigation.html) extension by Itoris. It allows filtering sub-categories from the parent category.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This shouldn't be too difficult. The code below is untested, but it should work wherever you put it in the front end. What it will do is give you access to the collection of sibiling categories, but you will need to figure out where in the templates you put it.

```
$parentId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentCategory()->getId();
$cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId)->getChildrenCategories();
foreach ($cats as $cat) {
  // first, skip current category.
  if ($cat->getId() == Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()) continue;
  // then do something with $cat
  echo $cat->getName().", ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to

> app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php

find function `_getItemsData()`

see line #163:

```
$categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();
```

remove this line and paste these

```
if(count($categoty->getChildrenCategories())){
    $categories = $categoty->getChildrenCategories();
}else{
    $categories = $categoty->getParentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
}
```

Comment: @RehanMonbin I tried your solution but In filter all other subcategories except selected one having `getProductCount()` zero. How I can get exactly same category filter block as parent category is active? Say If Animal category is selected then categories as cats (3), Dogs(5), Lions(4) then if Dogs is selected then cats and lions show active links with positive product count.

Comment: please consider overriding if you choose this solution

Answer (score 0):

This will retrieve the id, url and name of the sibling categories

```
$currentCategory = $this->helper('catalog/data')->getCategory();
$parentCategoryId = $currentCategory->parent_id;

$siblingCategoryIds = array();
$siblingCategories = array();

foreach(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId)->getChildrenCategories() as $siblingCategory) {
    if ($siblingCategory->getIsActive()) {
        $siblingCategories[] = array($siblingCategory->getId(), array('name' => $siblingCategory->getName(), 'url' => $siblingCategory->getUrl()));
        $siblingCategoryIds[] = $siblingCategory->getId();
    }
}

$pos = array_search($currentCategory->getId(), $siblingCategoryIds);

$nextPos = $pos+1;
$prevPos = $pos-1;

if (isset($siblingCategoryIds[$nextPos])) {
    $nextCategory = $siblingCategories[$nextPos];
}
else {
   $nextCategory = null;
}

if (isset($siblingCategoryIds[$prevPos])) {
    $prevCategory = $siblingCategories[$prevPos];
}
else {
   $prevCategory = null;
}

echo var_dump($prevCategory);
echo var_dump($nextCategory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Method app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php::getCurrentChildCategories() does what is needed and keeps product counts correct. You can copy it's functionality to your own helper.